# Web app design looks different on iphone and android/pc

Tags: android, css, ios

I am designing a web app. This is the link to that [web app](https://sheltered-reef-34219.herokuapp.com/hawker_centers/72b79859-9022-4b4a-be9c-3a537536c32f/5)
The design works as i want when i browse it using android device and my laptop. It also works fine when i use google chrome's development mode(ctrl+shift+i) to check on mobile compatibility on iphoneX.
However, when i use iphone to run the website, the design will be off. Check this images:

**Design that is shown on iphoneX:**

[image: Design that is shown on iphoneX:]

**Design i want:**

[image]

**Using chrome development device mode:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i can suggest you is to use `@media` queries in css this is used to make responsive website. This basically does that here you will define that what will happen if screen width changes or screen height changes. Give a look at following example :-

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: light blue;
  }
}
```

In this example we say that if maximum width of screen goes 600PX change the background color of body to light blue. In your case you are developing a progressive web app so you have to define so many media queries and play with margins, padding and other elements so that if anyone views on any device it should look fine